# Any ideas of how to integrate?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying the following integral,

$$\displaystyle \int_{k_{F}-q}^{k_{F}}\frac{dk}{q^{2}+2kq-\sigma\sqrt{4k_{so}^{2}k^{2}+k_{z}^{4}}+\sigma\sqrt{4k_{so}^{2}(k+q)^{2}+k_{z}^{4}}},$$

where $\sigma=\pm1$. However, I have not succeed so far. Any ideas of how I should analytically proceed?. I tried to solve it with Mathematica, using Integrate, however, it gives a really really long expression.

Of course, that instead of solving previous integral, I can focus on a limit case, where I get,

$$
\displaystyle \int \frac{4k_{so}(k^{2}+kq)}{k^{2}(-12k_{so}q-8\sigma k_{so}^{2})-8k_{so}k^{3}-k(4k_{so}q^{2}+8\sigma k_{so}^{2}q)+\sigma k_{z}^{4}}dk\,.
$$

Here, again I've tried with Mathematica, and it gives me some Root[...] that does not allow me to reduce the result.

Have you any ideas or tricks of how I should face this integral?.

Comment: whats the range of integration in the second integral?
i would guess, that q is small and k_f is big. This integral has it roots in condensed matter physics right?

Comment: For the second integral, you should be able to solve each by partial fractions since the numerator and denominator are polynomials of $k$, but this will probably take a ton of tedious algebra.  You will need to factor the denominator somehow... perhaps ask Mathematica to find the roots of the polynomial in the denominator?  It may also help to split it up into the sum of two fractions since there are two terms in the numerator, but I don't know if this will help.

Comment: @tired The range is the same as in the first integral. And yes, I am solving some condmat problems.

Comment: @nukeguy I tried to solve it using partial fractions, however, the roots of the polynomila in the denominator are solutions to a cubic equation...and therefore they are really long. Of course I tried with Mathematica, and it gives me the solutions in terms of Root[f,k], meaning that I should find the k'th solution of f==0...:( .

Comment: Have you tried rescaling the integral to reduce the number of independent parameters? Also, since approximations will probably have to be resorted to, are there any regimes in particular you're interested in?

Comment: @DavidH MM... i do have to integrate in k, so that the rest of parameters are constant. But how could it help upon integration? Do not see your point. Could you be more specific?. The regime that  is of interest, is the one one expressed in the second integral where the limits are the same as those in the first integral. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I am not a mathematician but when I see the integral first [Feynman parametrization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization) occurred my mind as a physicist. Maybe it would be helpful.
$$
\frac{1}{ABC}=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}dx dydz\delta(x+y+z-1)\frac{2}{(Ax+By+Cz)^3}
$$